# Hide API Key from Browser

Tags: javascript, php

I have an API Key that I use to retrieve information which is displayed on the browser. The problem I have is that using Chrome - Inspect Element - Source, the API key can be viewed. The code look like the following:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link href="/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
         var dbtKey = "<?php echo $apiKey; ?>";
```

The `$apiKey` is a var which sits in my config.php file: `$apiKey = 'my key'`

Is there any way I can prevent this from being displayed?

Comment: either use post method to pass data or encrypt, if it is serious use ssl

Comment: If that API key is required on the client side, so in the browser to access your server (that is not really clear from your description), then there is nothing you can do so really keep that key private. Question is in that case, _why_ you want to keep it private. Such a key certainly should not replace an authentiction all by itself. If so you have to change your architecture.

Comment: Could you not send the data from the client side to PHP then use the API key on the server, then send back a response. AKA Ajax

Comment: The API key that I have was supplied to me by a company. The intention of the API key is to allow visitors that come to the website to access information by making a selection from drop box fields. Although the company has granted permission for the code to be used on the website for visitors to view their database, they have asked for the API Key to be placed in a Proxy file. But I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: At the moment the file structure is there is a text.php file (The sample I placed in this question came from that). There is a css.php file and a "includes" folder which consists of a config.php file and a file called dbt.php. So in sort when a visitor comes to the website three selection boxes are displayed for book selection. 1. Language 2. Volume 3. Book after they make their selection the API key is used in a GET string to retrieve the information for the visitor. So I am trying to prevent someone taking the key for illegal purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to handle all the request via PHP and return the result as JSON which you can process client side.

For extra security, use SSL which will help against external threats but not internal.